# Error on custom symfony widget

Tags: php, symfony1, widget, symfony-1.4

I want to write a custom widget that extends from sfFormWidgetChoice.
However, I'm finding the guide on the symfony documentation kind of confusing.
I feel they just throw the completed code at us.
http://www.symfony-project.org/more-wit. Validators

I'm getting this error particularly:
Undefined index: Renderer_options

I know I'm doing something very wrong. I just don't know what I need to override on sfFormWidgetChoice.

Is it possible to create a widget that doesn't need any arguments?
can you provide steps on how to create a custom widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a custom widget you usually override the `configure` (to add custom options) and `render` (to modify the rendering of the widget) methods.

I think you get this error because you don't call the `configure` method of the parent class:

```
// in YourCustomWidget class 
protected function configure($options = array(), $attributes = array())
{
    parent::configure($options, $attributes);

    // add your options here
    $this->addRequiredOption('your_mandatory_option');
    $this->addOption('your_optional_option', 'default_value');
}
```

The `sfWidgetFormChoice` has only one required option ("argument" as you called it) the array of `choices` so you should pass it when create your widget:

```
// in your form class
$this->setWidget('your_field', new YourCustomWidget(array(
    `choices` => array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c')
)));
```

To customize the rendering of your widget override the render method (just like shown in [the docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/05-Custom-Widgets-and-Validators#chapter_05_building_a_simple_widget_and_validator)) an implement a custom logic.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix the error. Now i get the following runtime exception: YourCustomWidget requires the following options: 'choices'.

Im building the options['choices'] in YourCustomWidget configure method and passing it to parent::configure(). ¿Can you make a widget that doesnt recieve any arguments? ¿Is that wrong?

Comment: The required options are checked in constructor just before calling configure... but anyway why don't you just build choices in the form and pass them to the widget? Why you want to extend `sfWidgetFormChoice` if you don't want to pass choices? What kind of widget would you like to create? You should extend `sfWidget` or `sfWidgetForm` (if you would like to use an id or default value) and just override the `render` method.

Comment: Thanks, i solved the problem. Under configure() i did addOption('choices', myArray) and it worked... seems that it overrides the required option from sfWidgetFormChoices. Feels hacky, probably is wrong but it works...

I needed the sfWidgetFormChoice render() because i want a select combobox with the strings ordered in a special way.

Comment: Sorry, my statement "The required options are checked in constructor just before calling configure" was wrong, actually configure is the first call in the constructor so that's why you can do that. I think if you use your custom widget with the same choices all around in your code than it's in the right place.